# Get Specific Element on Different XMLs

Tags: c#, xml, string

I need to get a specific element from an `xml string` to know its corrensponding `concrete type` to `deserialize` it. Let's call `Function Code` as the specific element and getting this element is a little challenging for me.

Each `function code`'s corresponds to a specific schema design, and it looks like this:

```
1    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2    <Document xmlns="some.namespace.of.schema.design.1">
3      <SchemaDesign1>
4        <Header>
5          <FunctionCode>FunctionCode1</FunctionCode>
6          <OtherElement1>...</OtherElement1>
7          <OtherElement2>...</OtherElement2>
```

I need the value of the Function Code element on `line 5` which is `FunctionCode1`. But notice that on `line 3` that the element name is specific to its `concrete type` also.

So for another Function Code, e.g. `FunctionCode2`, the element on `line 3` will not be the same:

```
1    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2    <Document xmlns="some.namespace.of.schema.design.2">
3      <SchemaDesign2>
4        <Header>
5          <FunctionCode>FunctionCode2</FunctionCode>
6          <OtherElement1>...</OtherElement1>
7          <OtherElement2>...</OtherElement2>
```

I can only think of using `string.IndexOf("<FunctionCode>")` and get the `function code`'s value until it finds the respective closing tag. Is there a better approach for this without reading the whole string?

Here is a sample `XML` I got:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:caaa.013.001.07">
    <AccptrDgnstcReq>
        <Hdr>
            <MsgFctn>DGNP</MsgFctn>
            <PrtcolVrsn>6.0</PrtcolVrsn>
            <XchgId>378</XchgId>
            <CreDtTm>2013-08-08T22:18:35.07+02:00</CreDtTm>
            <InitgPty>
                <Id>66000001</Id>
                <Tp>OPOI</Tp>
                <Issr>ACQR</Issr>
            </InitgPty>
            <RcptPty>
                <Id>epas-acquirer-1</Id>
                <Tp>ACQR</Tp>
            </RcptPty>
        </Hdr>
        <DgnstcReq>
            <Envt>
                <Acqrr>
                    <Id>
                    <Id>9287351</Id>
                    </Id>
                    <ParamsVrsn>2013-08-07 08:00:00</ParamsVrsn>
                </Acqrr>
                <MrchntId>
                    <Id>EPASMER001</Id>
                </MrchntId>
                <POIId>
                    <Id>66000001</Id>
                    <Tp>OPOI</Tp>
                    <Issr>ACQR</Issr>
                </POIId>
            </Envt>
        </DgnstcReq>
        <SctyTrlr>
            <CnttTp>AUTH</CnttTp>
            <AuthntcdData>
                <Rcpt>
                    <KEK>
                        <KEKId>
                            <KeyId>SpecV1TestKey</KeyId>
                            <KeyVrsn>2010060715</KeyVrsn>
                            <DerivtnId>OYclpQE=</DerivtnId>
                        </KEKId>
                        <KeyNcrptnAlgo>
                            <Algo>DKP9</Algo>
                        </KeyNcrptnAlgo>
                        <NcrptdKey>4pAgABc=</NcrptdKey>
                    </KEK>
                </Rcpt>
                <MACAlgo>
                    <Algo>MCCS</Algo>
                </MACAlgo>
                <NcpsltdCntt>
                    <CnttTp>DATA</CnttTp>
                </NcpsltdCntt>
                <MAC>3Dahc1K96Pc=</MAC>
            </AuthntcdData>
        </SctyTrlr>
    </AccptrDgnstcReq>
</Document>
```

Comment: If you don't want to transform the whole string to an `XDocument`, you can use the `XmlReader` and parse the xml "piece by piece" until you arrive at `Document\SchemaDesign??\Header\FunctionCode`, or you can use a `XPathDocument` and do it through a XPath, like `/Document/*/Header/FunctionCode/text()`

Comment: @xanatos thanks for the input, I'll try that.

Comment: @KaeL - Please provide the complete XML examples (without the line numbers) so that we can actually code up a solution that we can test.

Comment: @Enigmativity - i'll try to mock one, but I cannot give the _complete_ one because I have 3 XSDs and 2 of them are quite long.

Comment: @KaeL - Sure, you can give the complete one. Why not?

Comment: @Enigmativity I updated my answer.

Comment: @KaeL - Can you please put the actual XML that you want decoded in your question? Please don't link to external sites. If the site disappears or changes its structure the links could become invalid and so would your question.

Comment: @KaeL - Right, that XML is very different from the original examples you posted. Which one do you need an answer for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given you have two `XDocument`, for each sample XML, called `doc1` and `doc2` respectively, then this code:

```
var ns1 = doc1.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
var ns2 = doc2.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var functionCode1 = doc1.Root.Descendants(ns1 + "FunctionCode").First().Value;
var functionCode2 = doc2.Root.Descendants(ns2 + "FunctionCode").First().Value;

Console.WriteLine(functionCode1);
Console.WriteLine(functionCode2);
```

...produces:

```
FunctionCode1
FunctionCode2
```

So, the general case for this, given you have an unknown XML document in this format, is:

```
var ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

var functionCode = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "FunctionCode").First().Value;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I am trying now.

Comment: I tried your answer and it is working. The `XML`s for other schema's should work as they have the same element name for `MsgFctn`. I am wondering how `XDocument` differs with using `XmlReader` for this situation.

Comment: @KaeL - `XmlReader` is part of the pre-LINQ set of XML tools. It is useful for reading large XML documents as it doesn't bring the whole thing in to memory. `XDocument`, on the other hand, does, so it should be used with caution when loading large documents. `XDocument`, though, is designed to be used with LINQ and it supports a much easier to understand model to traverse an XML document.

Comment: Thanks for the input. For now I am not concerned with the size of the XML messages I receive wouldn't be that large.